# Extraneous semicolon in PDF export

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When exporting from [my careers profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/rs), a semicolon gets added at the top of the export, it does not appear in preview.

Viewing in Foxit Reader 5.3.1.0606:

[image: Look at that semicolon!]

Comment: It's there to remind us that existence is fleeting, and that there are things in life we can not influence. Well, at least not without Adobe Acrobat!

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for the report, seems like this has been there for a while.  It will be fixed in the next push, probably tomorrow morning.